# Is it possible to add a facebook like button in the web app using python flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to implement a simple webapp where on a click of a button it pulls data from the database and displays on the webpage.As a part of this i need to implement a facebook like button and comment box to it? Is it possible to using python flask framework?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you're using templates to build your Flask app. If so, you'd just add an image with a link to your facebook page to the Flask template that controls headers/footers (assuming you want the 'like' button in the header/footer), e.g.

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/your.facebook.page"><img src="/path/to/facebook/icon/facebook.png" alt="Friend us on Facebook" title="Become a [your.company] Fan"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a real Flask / Python question.
Active Facebook elements are embedded into a webpage in the HTML code or in Javascript.
You have to edit the templates for your web application.

Details on the code to embed can be found at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/ and the sibling entries.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are asking, but [I have made authentication using github in one of my apps](https://github.com/DarkCrowz/corvid_site/blob/master/app/auth/github.py). I save the user in my db and use that user for comments in the rest of the app.

You probably want to use [flask-oauthlib](https://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), it seems like it is a pretty common extension for authentication and OAuth and it's not too hard to use

Answer (score 0):

No, flask itself can't be used. Just add `<a href="http://www.facebook.com/your.facebook.page"><img src="/path/to/facebook/icon/facebook.png" alt="Friend us on Facebook" title="Become a [your.company] Fan"></a>` to your template and it will work just fine - as stated by alex :)